# Android WebView get localstorage values

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I using Android WebView to load an URL, the web application uses cache and stores the value in browser **Application - > local Storage -> www.123xyz.com -> Scoring**

Whenever an activity in web application takes place, it will be stored in the local storage, it is working fine.

Now I want to retrieve that local storage values and store it in the SQLite database of android. If the web application does not perform correctly then I want to retrieve the values from SQLite database and set it in the Scoring Key of the local storage

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    Log.e("Database",getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()+"/databases/");
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()+"/databases/");
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    Log.e("Cache",getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()+"/scoring");
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()+"/scoring");
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    String url= getResources().getString(R.string.scoringurl);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Update:

Now I am able to access the localstorage through the below code and able to retrieve the values. Now I want to get this value for every 30 seconds or whenever there is a change takes place in localstorage.

Is there any way to do it. I guess it has to be done through timer and without making the application slower, can anyone help me.

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.evaluateJavascript("javascript:window.localStorage.getItem('scoring')", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                    Log.e("OnRecieve",s);
                }
            });
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: putting a timer that periodically check fro changes will do the task. right?

Answer (score 1):

call it on Override Method onConsoleMessage, every change in your console this Methods is called

```
    @Override
    public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
        view.evaluateJavascript("javascript:window.localStorage.getItem('scoring')", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override 
            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                Log.e("OnRecieve",s);
            }
        });
        super.super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID);
    }
```